# How to use coroutines without runBlocking?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Using `runBlocking` I block main thread which is not proper. I would like to implement it more efficient.

```
    private fun getWorkItem(parentProjectId: Int?): WorkItemRoom? {
        val workItemRepository by inject<WorkItemRepository>()
        var returnParent: WorkItemRoom? = null
        runBlocking {
            if (parentProjectId != null) {
                returnParent = workItemRepository.getWorkItem(parentProjectId)
            }
        }
        return returnParent
    }
```

This is where I use it:

```
                val parentProject = getWorkItem(parentProjectId) ?: return@setOnMenuItemClickListener false
```

The entire code surrounding with navigation, showing button etc. which is related to this `parentProject` data.

```
    private fun updateMenuItems() {
        with(requireContext()) {
            val data = viewModel.data.value?.dataOrNull

            editMenuItem?.isVisible = hasInternetConnection() && (data?.isProjectEditable ?: false)
            editMenuItem?.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
                findNavController().navigate(
                    ProjectDetailsFragmentDirections.actionProjectDetailsFragmentToWorkItemFragment(
                        workItemType = WorkItemType.PROJECT,
                        workItemId = args.projectId,
                        requestKey = workItemRequestKey
                    )
                )
                true
            }

            goToParentMenuItem?.isVisible = data?.parentProjectId != null
            goToParentMenuItem?.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
                val parentProjectId = data?.parentProjectId ?: return@setOnMenuItemClickListener false
                val parentProject = getWorkItem(parentProjectId) ?: return@setOnMenuItemClickListener false

                findNavController().navigate(
                    ProjectDetailsFragmentDirections.actionProjectDetailsFragmentSelf(
                        projectId = parentProjectId,
                        isArchived = parentProject.workItemState.isClosed
                    )
                )
                true
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally this is my suspend function

```
class GetWorkItemByIdUseCase(private val workItemDao: WorkItemDao) :
    BaseUseCase<Int, WorkItemRoom>() {
    override suspend fun create(id: Int): WorkItemRoom = workItemDao.getWorkItemById(id)
}
```

How would you change it to get rid of runBlocking? I have tried some solutions, but what only worked is runBlocking. Basically I need to wait for `returnParent` value when I use it in next lines.

Comment: I think you should research and read more document about MVVM, Clean Architecture then read Coroutine's document. There are many issues in your code. Short answer: Move the getWorkItem() into ViewModel, then use LiveData.

Comment: That is true, I fix the code after someone I do not like how it is done, but I won't change it. That is true I could use flow/livedata and just wait for the data I have done it like that in my other projects. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work but the question/`runBlocking` suggests a deeper misunderstanding of how coroutines work. Coroutines are leveraging being highly reactive and not asynchronous.

```
goToParentMenuItem?.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        val parentProjectId = data?.parentProjectId ?: return@setOnMenuItemClickListener false
        val parentProject = getWorkItem(parentProjectId) ?: return@setOnMenuItemClickListener false

        findNavController().navigate(
            ProjectDetailsFragmentDirections.actionProjectDetailsFragmentSelf(
                    projectId = parentProjectId,
                    isArchived = parentProject.workItemState.isClosed
            )
        )
    }
    true
}

private suspend fun getWorkItem(parentProjectId: Int?): WorkItemRoom? = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val workItemRepository by inject<WorkItemRepository>()
    var returnParent: WorkItemRoom? = null
    if (parentProjectId != null) {
        workItemRepository.getWorkItem(parentProjectId)
    } else {
        null
    }
}
```

Comment: return' is not allowed here I need to change it to @launch, but then i don't return false in setOnMenuItemClickListener

Comment: @Chris you have brackets wrong. The `true` should be outside of the launch.

Comment: I know, I'm talking about something different. In the way you bring your proposition there is no way of "return@setOnMenuItemClickListener false", but I have just make variable with ifs to change it. Thanks man. it works

Comment: @Chris I went over this again and you can. As I understand `data?.parentProjectId` is not a coroutine value and since `getWorkItem` relies on it being non-null you can assume if first is null, second will be as well and that is your `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest simply marking `getWorkingItem()` with `suspend`, which will allow it to call other suspending functions without having to invoke a coroutine builder function. You can then use your ViewModel's scope to launch a coroutine to call `getWorkingItem()`:

```
val parentProject = viewModelScope.async {
  getWorkItem(parentProjectId)
} 
if (parentProject.await() == null) return@setOnMenuItemClickListener false
```

**EDIT:** Added the `await()` call on `parentProject`.

Comment: I think it won't work, because there is no .await() and IMO it starts coroutine and immediately check for parentProject == null with no 100% certanty that will be done.

Comment: You're right, you'd need an `await()`, I updated the answer.

Comment: I have the same idea, but the problem is .await should be also done in coroutine so the entire thing should be done with GlobalScope.launch {} which is not nice and also parentProject should be define earlier before this GlobalScope

Comment: True, the answer you accepted looks like a better approach!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `CoroutineScope` interface and call `launch` to start a coroutine within methods of that class.

This [official tutorial](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-and-channels.html) may help.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32970525)

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti you mean like including "You can implement the `CoroutineScope` interface and call `launch` to start a coroutine within methods of that class." here?  Like they did?